# Python Loop running one extra time

Tags: python

```
BillItemCounter=0
TotalBill=0
BillItems=0
BillItemType=""

BillItems=int(input("enter the number of Items on your Bill"))
for BillItemCounter in range(BillItems):
   BillItemType=str(input("enter the item type"))
   if BillItemType!= "c" and BillItemType!= "t" and BillItemType!= "b":
    print ("enter an appropriate item type")
BillItemType=str(input("enter the item type"))

if BillItemType == "c":
    TotalBill= TotalBill + 2.25
elif BillItemType == "t":
     TotalBill= TotalBill + 1.85
else: TotalBill= TotalBill + 3.05
```

If I enter 2 it runs 3 times - as far as I can see it should run correctly I know the issue will be to do with nesting but just cannot see it thanks

Comment: the `str()` in `str(input())`is unnecessary.

Comment: It's not that the loop is running one extra time, it's that you're asking the `"enter the item type"` one more time after the loop is done.

Answer (score 2):

The loop isn't running 3 times, you just had an additional "enter the item type" at the very end.

Comment: Given this, the question should be closed as due to a typo instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I wouldn't consider it "a typo", but yes, I agree that it should be closed instead.

Comment: We use that close reason for all trivial editing mistakes where there's no lasting value to other posters.

Comment: Why can't it just be deleted?